# Sorting by date PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find all files that include some string and are not older than "x" days. Those files have to be sorted and then sent in .txt format.

The code seemed fine to me, but it doesn´t filter files by date. All other cmdlets work as intended, but the part `Where-Object  {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)}` doesn´t seem to be working at all.

Do you have any recommendations how to fix it?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)} |
    Select-String -Pattern $searched |
    Group-Object -Property Path, Filename |
    select Name |
    Out-File -Filepath C:\tmp\output.txt
```

Comment: The filter should work, unless you didn't define `$days` (in which case you'd be looking for files newer than right now).

Answer (score 4):

```
| Sort-Object -Property propertyName -Descending
```

cmdlet to sort by property value
reference link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-6